# Fix groovy Script to mail to multiple receipients

Tags: groovy

monitoringemail.groovy file has below cal def:

```
def call(details = "") {
    def emailBody = "Build URL: " + env.Build_URL + '\n\n'
    emailBody += details
    mail( to: 'monitoring@company.com',
        subject: "Build failed in Jenkins:" + currentBuild.projectName + " " + currentBuild.fullDisplayName,
        body: emailBody)
}
```

---

and this monitoringemail.groovy file right now called in Jenkinsfile using method like monitoringemail() to send mail notification.

monitoringemail()
Ex:
Inside Jenkinsfile we will groovy file using method:

```
failure {
            monitoringemail()
        }
```

---

I want declare below email variables in monitoringemail.groovy file

```
NW_TEAM = 'net1 net2'
JOBDSL_OWNER = 'jobdsl'
CLIENT_TEAM = 'client1 client2 client3'
CD_JOB_OWNERS = 'cd1 cd2 cd3'
QA_OWNERS = 'staging1 staging3 staging4'
```

and update th monitoringemail.groovy file so i can call the

monitoringemail() using parameters.

monitoringemail()

monitoringemail(NW_TEAM)

monitoringemail(NW_TEAM,CLIENT_TEAM)

monitoringemail() means i can send email to infra@company.com by default

monitoringemail(NW_TEAM) means i can send email to net1@company.com and net2@company.com

monitoringemail(NW_TEAM,CLIENT_TEAM) means i can send email to net1@company.com, net2@company.com, client1@company.com, client2@company.com and client3@company.com

** TASK ** is to update monitoringemail.groovy file to support multiple parameters. right now as soon as we call method monitoringemail()its sending mails to monitoring@company.com.

We want kill this "monitoring@company.com" address usage and call explicitly monitoringemail(NW_TEAM) or monitoringemail(NW_TEAM, CLIENT_TEAM) so monitoringemail.groovy has capabilities so it can send emails to respective team user emails alerts.

Requirement changed a bit: (Need to enum and a seperate file)

```
JobOwner.groovy
enum JobOwner {
    NW_TEAM('net1, net2'),
    JOBDSL_OWNER('jobdsl'),
    CLIENT_OWNERS('client1, client2, client3'),
    CD_JOB_OWNERS('cd1,cd2'),
    QA_OWNERS('staging1, staging2, staging3')
 
    String recipients
 
    JobOwner(String recipients) {
        this.recipients = recipients
    }
 
    List<String> getRecipients() {
        return recipients.split(',').collect { it.trim() }
    }
}


sendEmail.groovy
def sendEmail(details = "", JobOwner... teams) {
    def recipients = teams.collect { it.getRecipients() }.flatten()
 
    recipients = recipients ?: ['infra'] 
 
    recipients.each { recipient ->
        def emailRecipient = recipient + "@company"
        def emailBody = "Build URL: " + env.Build_URL + '\n\n'
        emailBody += details
 
        mail(to: emailRecipient,
             subject: "Build failed in Jenkins: ${currentBuild.projectName} ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
             body: emailBody)
    }
}
```

How does this look now

Comment: Added question in the end if that helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do that:

```
NW_TEAM = [
   "net1@company.com", 
   "net2@company.com"
]
JOBDSL_OWNER = ["jobdsl@company.com"]
CLIENT_TEAM = [
   "client1@company.com", 
   "client2@company.com", 
   "client3@company.com"
]
CD_JOB_OWNERS = [
   "cd1@company.com", 
   "cd2@companyd.com", 
   "cd3@company.com" 
]
QA_OWNERS = [
   "staging1@company.com", 
   "staging3@company.com", 
   "staging4@company.com"
]

def sendEmail(toEmail = ['infra@company.com'], details = "") {
    mail( to: toEmail.join(" "),
        subject: "Build failed in Jenkins: ${currentBuild.projectName} ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
        body: """
Build URL: ${env.Build_URL}

${details}
""")
}
```

I've taken advantage of some Groovy features to shorten things a bit more.  There's more ways to make this even more flexible, but this should meet what you wanted to do.

So `sendEmail` has been renamed from `call`.  And now you send a list of email addresses you want to send things to.

```
sendEmail()  // sends to infra@company.com
sendEmail(NW_TEAM)   // sends to NW_TEAM = [ 'net1@company.com', 'net2@company.com' ]
sendEmail(NW_TEAM + CLIENT_TEAM) // sends to NW_TEAM and CLIENT_TEAM
sendEmail(NW_TEAM + CLIENT_TEAM + CD_JOB_OWNERS, "Some Important Details...")
```

Comment: Updated the question @chubbsondubs , thanks for your response.
Now i was asked to use enum for comma separated recipients and test it.

Comment: Um ok.  Well looks like you have it mostly handled.  I still don't know why you keep using a comma separate list stored as a String to represent the recipients if you're going to just hard code them in Enums.  Doing that is causing a fair most of more code to be written and executed repeatedly.  You also don't need to send the email within the `each` closure either.  There's little reason to use the each there.  `mail( to: recipients.collect { "${it}@company.com" }...)` . You can just put all of the emails in the to line and send it once to everyone.  That will cut down on email traffic.